# How To Stop Video Auto Playing

Tags: html

I'm using Bootstrap 4. My embedded video plays automatically when the page loads. My code is:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 hoverable video-1 video-align">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="myvideo.mp4" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

How do I stop the auto-play, please?

Comment: Use the `<video>` tag?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use an iframe; use the video tag. An inline frame is there to display another document on the page and is automatically rendered when the page is loaded. In case of a video, it is automatically played.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `autoplay="false"` like this:

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls="controls" type="video/mp4" preload="none">
<source src="myvideo.mp4" autoplay="false">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

That should be it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this additional parameter for the iframe:

```
autoplay="false"
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. I also wanted to keep the video responsive and to have the first part of the video as the thumbnail. I used the above information and hunted around some more and my cide is now: